# Scimago (Scopus) or Journal Citations Report? Which one is more important?

Tags: citations, journals, bibliometrics

I am aware that Scrimago and JCR are both authoritative sources. It seems that Scrimajo includes more journals.
I was wondering which one of them is more widely used and more important?

Comment: Which one is your boss using as a KPI?

Answer (score 1):

JCR is easily the gold standard. It's the one that is used to calculate the impact factor, after all.

A heuristic is, the fewer journals are indexed, the more exclusive the index, and therefore the more prestigious.